# Condition throws always the exception in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to work with arrays in Java, specifically in a method that delete the first appear of one element passed by param (or in this case make that the matched value convert to a 0), in this method I use a throwable exception if the matched value don't appear in the Array, but for any reason, this exception is always throwed.

Here is de code of the method:

```java
public static void deleteElement(int[] array, int element) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == element) {
                array[i] = 0;
                break;
            } else if (array[i] != element) {
                throw new Exception("Element not found");
            }
        }
    }
```

When I call the method like this:

```java
int[] array = new int[10];

try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                System.out.print("Introduce un numero: ");
                array[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }

try {
    Arrayaba.deleteElement(array, 10);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // The exception is always throwed
}
```

Showing the next error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Element not found
        at LibreriaArraysBoludos.Arrayaba.deleteElement(Arrayaba.java:104)
        at TestArrayaba.main(TestArrayaba.java:23)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.execute(Main.java:434)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:205)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:132)
```

If any extra information is needed say it to me. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You only check the very first element.

Comment: What if the element is not the first? Then `array[i] != element` will be true for `i = 0` and the exception is thrown. You want to keep track of whether the element was found or not (e.g. using a boolean flag) and _after_ the loop you throw the exception if the element was not found. In your case you'd not even need a flag: just throw the exception after the loop and exit the method (and the loop) early using `return;` instead of `break;` after the element was deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to throw the exception only when you have visited all the array, not at the first different element

```
public static void deleteElement(int[] array, int element) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == element) {
                array[i] = 0;
                return;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Element not found");
    }
```

Comment: This can be a LOT simpler; remove `found`, replace `found = true; break;` with `return;`, then delete `if(!found)` etc. Removes half the lines at least. Also, just posting a snippet isn't a proper way to answer SO questions. First explain what's wrong with OP's approach, then if you want, explain the right approach, illustrated with code or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that if this array[i] is not equal to the specified element in for, an exception will be thrown. First, i=0 , array[i]=element or not, if it is, it will be 0, and if it is not, an exception will be thrown. This is what your code says. In this case, this code only works when array[0]=element, and if not, an exception is thrown. What you are looking for is as follows:

```
public static void deleteElement(int[] array, int element) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == element) {
                array[i] = 0;
                break;
            } 
          }
                throw new Exception("Element not found");
        }
```